# Headers in ListView from cursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a sql table with columns 'word' and 'date'.  I'm using a CursorAdapter to show a word list in ListView. Word list is divided by headers with date. Words with the same date must be in one section with one header.
For example:
**22 July**
Book
Ball
**21 July**
Summer
**20 July**
Bus
Tree

When I open the app, headers are working fine. But after scrolling headers are starting to change position and make sections for words with different dates. How to fix it?

```
public class DataCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private int mDateColumnIndex;
private int mCurrentView = 0; //if 0 - then with header

public DataCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    int position = cursor.getPosition();
    mDateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DATE);
    if (position == 0){
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_header, parent, false);
    }
    String date = cursor.getString(mDateColumnIndex);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position-1);
    String datePrevious = cursor.getString(mDateColumnIndex);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    if (date.equals(datePrevious)){
        mCurrentView = 1;
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    else
    {
        mCurrentView = 0;
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_header, parent, false);
    }

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView wordTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_word);
    int wordColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_WORD_WORD);
    String word = cursor.getString(wordColumnIndex);
    wordTextView.setText(word);
    if (mCurrentView == 0){
        TextView dateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_date);
        String date = cursor.getString(mDateColumnIndex);
        dateTextView.setText(date);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

}

Comment: if you want to have 2 different view types you have to override `getViewTypeCount` - now it returns 1 (the default) and  `getItemViewType` - now it always return 0 (the default)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the hint, now the app's working properly. You can add it as answer.

Comment: @notChosen Can you post the changes here? Thanks